# Factoryboy can not generate database-dependent field

Tags: django, pytest, factory-boy

I use [django-cities-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/issues/183) to store the user locations. However I need to import a huge dataset of countries & cities to the database.

I use `Factory` classes for both testing and creating dummy data on the site.

How can I create a factory that would automatically populate these fields during the tests?

When not testing, the factory works properly by `Country.objects.all()`. But when testing, the database is empty and can not find any countries: `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`.

What should be the right approach for such cases? If you have a better solution to the use of LazyAttributes below, let me know the better approach.

```py
class UserProfileFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    # ...


    birth_country = FuzzyChoice(Country.objects.all()) or None
    birth_region = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: o.birth_country.region_set.order_by("?").first()
    )
    birth_subregion = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: o.birth_region.subregion_set.order_by("?").first()
    )
    birth_city = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: o.birth_region.city_set.order_by("?").first()
    )
```

Comment: Do you need to have all of these fields? Couldn't you just store `birth_city` and then the other attributes can be retrieved by accessing them from the city? `birth_city. birth_subregion. birth_region. birth_country`

Comment: It definitely makes sense. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: As for your issue, you need to create factories for the related models and then use subfactories

Comment: If I use SubFactories and use random names for the Country/Region/Subregion/City, that works for test. However I wanted them to be realistic when I used them for the Demo page. United Kingdom / Île-de-France / Madrid would look weird. Maybe I should use pre-defined combinations and ask the factory to pick randomly among these combinations.

Comment: If you want/need realistic data, could you not load the fixtures from the package before your tests?